# FastAPI + Appwrite.io in docker-compose prod/dev setup?

Tags: docker-compose, appwrite

Found out about [appwrite.io](https://appwrite.io/) and I really like the features appwrite offers. It's similar to the Firebase, but open source.

I'm trying to make appwrite work with Python/FastAPI.

Bellow it the folder structure of the project. Folder `api` will contain all additional the logic. `Dockerfile` is taken from [uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker) repo.

```sh
├── project
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── app
│      ├── api 
│      ├── Dockerfile
│      ├── main.py
│      ├── requirements.txt
└──
```

In the docker-compose file I added the `app` service which starts FastAPI.

```
version: '3'

services:

    app:
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
            
    traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.1.4
        command:
            - --providers.file.directory=/storage/config
            - --providers.file.watch=true
            - --providers.docker=true
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
            - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 5000:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - appwrite-config:/storage/config:ro
            - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:ro
        depends_on:
            - appwrite
        networks:
            - gateway
            - appwrite
    
    appwrite:
        image: appwrite/appwrite:0.6.2
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite
        labels:
            - traefik.http.routers.appwrite.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
            - traefik.http.routers.appwrite-secure.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
            - traefik.http.routers.appwrite-secure.tls=true
        volumes:
            - appwrite-uploads:/storage/uploads:rw
            - appwrite-cache:/storage/cache:rw
            - appwrite-config:/storage/config:rw
            - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:rw
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - redis
            - smtp
            - influxdb
            - telegraf
        environment:
            - _APP_ENV=production
            - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1=your-secret-key
            - _APP_DOMAIN=localhost
            - _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET=localhost
            - _APP_REDIS_HOST=redis
            - _APP_REDIS_PORT=6379
            - _APP_DB_HOST=mariadb
            - _APP_DB_PORT=3306
            - _APP_DB_SCHEMA=appwrite
            - _APP_DB_USER=user
            - _APP_DB_PASS=password
            - _APP_INFLUXDB_HOST=influxdb
            - _APP_INFLUXDB_PORT=8086
            - _APP_STATSD_HOST=telegraf
            - _APP_STATSD_PORT=8125
            - _APP_SMTP_HOST=smtp
            - _APP_SMTP_PORT=25

    mariadb:
        image: appwrite/mariadb:1.0.3
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite
        volumes:
            - appwrite-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootsecretpassword
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=appwrite
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        command: 'mysqld --innodb-flush-method=fsync'

    smtp:
        image: appwrite/smtp:1.0.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite
        environment:
            - MAILNAME=appwrite
            - RELAY_NETWORKS=:192.168.0.0/24:10.0.0.0/16

    redis:
        image: redis:5.0
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite
        volumes:
            - appwrite-redis:/data:rw

    
    influxdb:
        image: influxdb:1.6
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite
        volumes:
            - appwrite-influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb:rw

    telegraf:
        image: appwrite/telegraf:1.0.0
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - appwrite

networks:
    gateway:
    appwrite:

volumes:
    appwrite-mariadb:
    appwrite-redis:
    appwrite-cache:
    appwrite-uploads:
    appwrite-certificates:
    appwrite-influxdb:
    appwrite-config:
```

I tried docker-compose `links` and `networks` to `appwrite` but none of them worked.
Bellow is the error I get when I try to use python appwrite sdk.

```
{"result":"HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/database/collections (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5517795d60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding custom Docker containers to Appwrite**

https://dev.to/streamlux/adding-custom-docker-containers-to-appwrite-2chp

Can also refer to -

**Learn How to Run Appwrite With Your Own Custom Proxy or Load Balancer**

https://dev.to/appwrite/learn-how-to-run-appwrite-with-your-own-custom-proxy-or-load-balancer-28k

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.